# Make a Low-Poly Object with an equal balanced number of Vertices

Tags: modeling, texturing

I'm trying to model a Low-Poly sky island but I can't get the mesh to have an equal number of vertices at each side.
If i try to model it it looks somthing like this:
[image: Model]

1. I want the vertices to be equally distributes across the whole mesh. My model has much more vertices at the bottom than at the top (technically both sides have an equal amount of vertices but the top side has more area)
2. My model doesn't really look like the Low-Poly models currently used in games e.g.:
   [image: Low-Poly model used in games]
   It would be very helpful if anyone can show me how to model a good looking Low-Poly floating island. (The top shouldn't be too uneven, because I will create houses on top of the Islands in a game)
3. I'm not very experienced in texturing models, so I don't know how to texture Low-Poly models correctly. Should I use Vertex-Paint or UV-Mapping? How can I Import the textures correctly into Unity? What should I do to achive a texture and lighting like picture 2?

Thanks in Advacne,
Sebastian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For redistributing the verts try the remesh modifier.

To make your model look more like the picture you posted, you have to lower your polycount, which you can do by editing parameters in the remesh modifier I mentioned or by retopologizing manually.

As for good low poly modeling, there are plenty of tutorials, and that's not something I can answer here. It'll take practice and patience, as low poly is harder than it looks.

For texturing, since it's done on a face-by-face basis, do not use UVs or textures, but instead use multiple materials and assign different materials to different faces.

Lighting like that is decently simple. Flat shading, a directional light, and some global illumination. If you're using Unity, also look into the image effects standard assets, like screen space ambient occlusion or color correction. After that, just iterate.

Comment: Which mesh would you recommend me to start with? An upside down cone, a circle which i extrude and merge at the bottom or something else?

Comment: @BlackThunder I'm not sure what you're asking. For tutorial topics, go with whatever interests you the most.